# Framework gets deleted from app bundle after redeploy on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

After cleaning the build and deploying the app for the first time (both on a physical device and a simulator), it works the way it's supposed to. But after I change something and redeploy, SkiaSharp (*libSkiaSharp.framework*) and Realm (*realm-wrappers.framework*) don't get added to the app bundle Frameworks folder.

Other frameworks get added as usual after redeploys, but these two don't.

I already tried to disable incremental builds and device-specific builds, and it didn't fix it. I don't have a clue why this is happening.

Comment: How do you know those framework don't get added to the app bundle Frameworks folder?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT The app crashes when launching with a “dylib: library not found” error. The error said the library path was “@rpath/realm-wrappers.framework”, so to understand what was wrong I took a look at this folder and saw that it was missing. After cleaning the build and deploying the app for the first time, this folder is there together with the SkiaSharp one, then, if I redeploy, both get deleted, but if I manually add the frameworks to the app bundle the app works.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Have a look at [this thread](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1871) may help.

Comment: Thank you for your help @JackHua-MSFT but I already read this thread and it’s not the same error. The one from this thread happens on every launch and only on physical devices, mine only happens on redeploys, simulators are affected and it’s not specific to Realm (SkiaSharp framework gets deleted too).

Comment: What's your linker behavior? Would it work if you change to other options?

Comment: Nope, I'm in debug mode so it's set to Don't Link. It's working in Release mode with linker enabled but I don't think it has anything to do with it, basically the release mode always ignores the already built bundle, fixing the issue as it only happens on redeploys.

Comment: Well, it really strange as it works in the first time.

Comment: Hey @JackHua-MSFT, thanks for your help, I was having this issue for quite some time but it got fixed with the latest Xamarin.Forms update. This happened some time ago and the issue came back, but for now, it's fixed. 

Comment: Glad to hear that you have fixed this issue, you can share the solution in the answer and mark it which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Yeah, I was deciding if I should do that, because like I said, this happened before. But ok, I will mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to Xamarin.Forms 4.8 the issue was fixed.